# Facing error in applying classifier model

Tags: classification, xgboost, xgbclassifier

I am facing the following error even after encoding the categorical columns:

ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter`enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.  Invalid columns:hotel: object, arrival_date_month: object, meal: object, country: object, market_segment: object, distribution_channel: object, reserved_room_type: object, assigned_room_type: object, deposit_type: object, customer_type: object, reservation_status: object, reservation_status_date: object

The code is:
model = XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

I am expecting to find out the fault in my codeand provide me the correct way.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode (one-hot encoding or label encoding) categorical variables or drop them.

Comment: I have already encoded categorical variables by one-hot enoding. Still it is showing this error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).